# OpenSUSE can only boot into Failsafe mode

Tags: drivers, opensuse, touchpad, zypper

I installed the latest version of OpenSUSE and tried to install the driver for my touchpad. It would not install, so I installed it in this way:

```
zypper install ./filename_.rpm
```

After that my OpenSUSE will not load. When I boot and choose OpenSUSE in the Grub menu, I only see the OpenSUSE logo (about 4sec) and then only a black screen.

Failsafe mode is working.

Is it possible that the system isn't working due to the driver I installed? If yes, is there a way to "delete" the driver, which I installed or maybe remove it from startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter in Failsafe mode and remove the package, using `rpm -e package_name`.

Comment: In failsafe, login as `root` and remove the package. (Possibly rebuild the main kernel image with `mkinitcpio`?) Not familiar with opensuse.

Comment: @hesse That too is possible, but the OP says that his system only starts in failsafe mode.

Comment: Adjusted the comment to reflect what I really meant.